# Android Phone Gap Installation Queries

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova, ant

I have gone through the following steps for phonegap installation

I extracted phonegap and saved it in `D:\phonegap-2.9.1` folder

then i saved ADT in `D:\username-Software\Android\eclipse`

I extracted apache-ant and saved in

```
C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.3
```

I got java in

```
C:\Program Files\Java
```

My Environment variable paths are 
as seen below under system variables

```
JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41;


Path 

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;"C:\Program Files\Common Files\EMC";D:\username-Software\Android\sdk\platforms;D:\username-Software\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;D:\username-Software\Android\sdk\tools;
```

Am I missing something ???

I have gone through

http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/building-a-phonegap-android-app-on-windows-cordova-2-2-0-with-eclipse/

Because when I run ant it gives error

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

I get error after creating android project

Following are the errors as seen in image

[image: Errors in Android Project]

I get it right till step 6 as seen in the link

```
6. I got the following readout from Command Prompt:

Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.7
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Creating new android project…
Copying template files…
Copying js, jar & config.xml files…
Copying cordova command tools…
Updating AndroidManifest.xml and Main Activity…

D:\PhoneGap\phonegap-phonegap-2.2.0-0-g8a3aa47\phonegap-phonegap-8a3aa47\lib\and
roid\bin>

7. I found all the files set in the location I indicated.
```

But when i saw the project It had errors!!!

Am i missing something ???

I seem to not find cordova.jar library ... its not even in phonegap-2.9.1 folder how can I fix it ??

Comment: in eclipse, did you add both your project and the other one with -cordovalib in it's name?

Comment: Why and where are you trying to run `ant`? Is there any reason you can't use a 3.x version of cordova/phonegap?

Comment: Could you try out based on the instructions on this blog.http://csharpwavenet.blogspot.sg/2014/04/creating-phonegap-project-with-android.html Let me know if this does not resolve ill help you from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already resolved it by including cordova library 
It always goes missing while having it as first build